# My Ajax code is only getting the value of one row from Mysql database rows

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

```
create table comment(id int not null auto_increment primary key, comment text);
```

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from comment order by id desc");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $main_id = $rows["id"];
    $comment = $rows["comment"];

    echo "<input type='hidden' id='main_id' value=\"$main_id\"/>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='comment' value=\"$comment\"/>";
    echo "<div id='edit_field'><p>$comment</p></div>" . "\n";
    echo "<a href='#' id='edit'> edit</a>" . "\n";
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#edit').click(function() {

      var id = $('#main_id').val();
      var comment = $('#comment').val();
      var varData = 'id='+id+'&comment='+comment;

      $.ajax ({

        type: "POST",
        url: "edit_field.php",
        data: varData,
        success: function(data) {
        $("#edit_field").html(data);
       }
      });
}); 


require_once('lib/functions.php');

$con = connect();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from comment where id = $_POST[id]");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $id = $rows["id"];

  $comment = $rows["comment"];

  echo "<textarea cols='40' name='comment' rows='4'>$comment</textarea>";
}
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple DOM elements with the same id. The id needs to be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $main_id = $rows["id"];
    $comment = $rows["comment"];

    echo "<input type='hidden' class='main_id' id='main_id_$main_id' value=\"$main_id\"/>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' class='comment' id='comment_$main_id' value=\"$comment\"/>";
    echo "<div class='edit_field'><p>$comment</p></div>" . "\n";
    echo "<a href='#' class='edit' id='edit_$main_id'> edit</a>" . "\n";
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.edit').click(function() {
      var lnk = $(this);
      var rowId = lnk.attr('id');
      var rowIdParts = rowId.split('_');

      var id = rowIdParts[1];
      var comment = $('#comment_'+id).val();
      var varData = 'id='+id+'&comment='+comment;

      $.ajax ({

        type: "POST",
        url: "edit_field.php",
        data: varData,
        success: function(data) {
        $("#edit_field").html(data);
       }
      });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sumit! I appreciate for swift reply. I'm new to javascript, so seems my problems is solved. Thanks, Tashi Delek!!!

Comment: #edit_field needs to be modified in the same way other fields were modified by me, further try to send your data to Server in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you Amal and Sumit, you guys gave me exactly I want.

Comment: @Amal Murali! Edition for each row is now working perfect. So, if I click on 3rd row, the box should be placed on third row. How can I edit   echo "<div class='edit_field'><p>$comment</p></div>" . "\n"; Thank you!